# How to loop through range names and hide rows if cell = 0?

Tags: vba, excel

I have several VBA routines in an Excel 2007. There is a template worksheet which gets copied (and accordingly altered) up to 50 times. Now, this template contains a range called "HideRows", so this range gets copied several times in all those new worksheets. I want to hide all rows that contain the value `0` in the range "HideRows". Not all rows shall be hidden, only those rows that contain the value `0`. This is what I've got so far:

```
Option Explicit 
Sub HideEmptyRows()

    Dim rngName As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each rngName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If rngName.Name = "HideRows" Then
            With cell
                For Each cell In rngName
                    If .Value = 0 Then
                    .EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    End If
                Next cell
            End With
        End If
    Next rngName
```

What's wrong here and what do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: `And Not IsEmpty(cell)` or some other thing would bring you closer to "contain the value" instead of *has the value*.

Comment: Echoing pnuts, it's difficult for us to help if you don't say what's working and what isn't (and what happens when it doesn't work). You might, for example, say you are receiving a Type Mismatch error in your `For Each rngName ...` line, and we could suggest you declared rngName as Name; or you might say you are receiving an Object doesn't support this property or method error in your `For Each cell in rngName` line, and we might propose you change that to `... rngName.RefersToRange`, etc.

Comment: Sorry guys, you're right of course! I'll add that as soon as I can! I'll be back soon, to fix that.

Comment: Ambie is right. However, I do not get further with that rngName.RefersToRange because the compiler says there's Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.
Thank you a lot for your help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can address the named range directly without looping. There is no test that this named range exists, as per your description it is safe to assume so.
Secondly, do not use the "with" statement outside of the loop that sets the referenced variable. Try this instead:

```
Option Explicit 
Sub HideEmptyRows()

    Dim rngName As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In range("HideRows")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**edit:**
If the workbook contains multiple identical sheets where each sheet may contain this named range you will have to loop. This code will not loop over all names but over all sheets, and test for existance of the named range in each sheet:

```
Sub HideEmptyRows()
    Dim sh As Sheets
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Set rng = Nothing  ' this is crucial!
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = sh.Names("HideRows")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each cell In rng
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value = 0)
            Next cell
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

The range variable has to be reset explicitly before the assignment as this step is skipped if the range does not exist. The following `If` would use the value last assigned then, which would be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In order to keep the code short, I did not test if there is a such range at all, but thank you to tell me so.
However, as I already pointed out, there are several ranges with the name "HideRows". That is why I used to loop - but I will check this as soon as I can.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me.